# Debug WCF Service on remote calls

Tags: wcf, debugging

I would like to debug incoming requests to my service on remote calls (at least on calls from machines on the same network). What do I need to achieve this? As of now I can only debug local requests. Otherwise the breakpoints wont be hit.

I hosting my service on IIS.

Comment: is IIS on your local machine or on another machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to get a full Visual Studio Debugging experience in the setup you describe.  Simply deploy your app to IIS and get it running. Then from within visual studio Choose Debug -> Attach To process.  In this window be sure to tick "Show Processes from all users".  After doing this click the refresh button.  When that is done, locate the IIS process in question (w3wp.exe) in the task list and click attach.

Comment: Alright I do this and my breakpoints get transparents and says "Breakpoint will not be hit, No symbols has been loaded..". How do I load those symbols?

Comment: You will need to make sure they are being built with your project and deploy them to the bin directory of your site (*.pdb).  If they are not being generated open project properties -> build -> (click advanced button in bottom right corner of window) -> Debug Info: PDB-only

Comment: They are in the bin foler of my site. However I'm trying to add the symbols manually but it says "No matching symbols found for pdg file" or something similar.

Comment: Are you running the site in debug mode? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8z01xdh.aspx

Comment: Yes I am according to your link. It just seem to be having trouble finding symbols when i attach Inetmgr.exe process

Comment: Alright I solved it by some googling. I should attach to process w3wp.exe, not Inetmgr.exe. At first I could'nt find w3wp.exe in my list, took me a while to understand that it was because I had stopped all program pool in IIS. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

To debug a WCF Service, you can add the following configuration in your web.config :

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\temp\WEBTraces.log" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

You have to create a folder named `temp` in `C:\`.

It will log every request of your service in a XML file.

Hope it helps !

Comment: I asked for debugging with breakpoints, but thanks for the information